# NextGen Gallery different thumbnail size per gallery

Tags: plugin-nextgen-gallery

How can I instruct NextGen Gallery to use different thumbnail sizes for different galleries. I have different gallery templates for use in different parts of the site, and the sizes of the thumbnails are not the same. At the moment I have to stay generating the thumbnails through the gallery management page, it would be much better if I could set the thumbnail size for each gallery once and for all. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Templates

The most important feature improvement in Version 1.00 is the template engine. Custom templates are PHP files that can be stored in the folder nggallery, inside your theme directory. NextGEN gallery look up always first into this folder if there are the vaild template file. For example, if you are using the default WordPress theme then you can store a template file at :

```
/wp-content/themes/default/nggallery/gallery-sample1.php
```

To use now this template in a post or page you insert the tag:

```
[nggallery id=1 template=sample1]
```

This tells NextGEN Gallery to use ‘gallery-sample1.php’ to show the gallery output. Without this template tag, NextGEN takes the default template (gallery.php) from the plugin folder (unless you copy it to your theme folder), normally located at :

```
/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/view/gallery.php
```

The same you can use for album, singlepic or imagebrowser, all of them are template driver so that you can easily modify the output without having problems during a upgrade.

**Resource:** http://nextgen-gallery.com/templates/

Answer (score 1):

You must to do:

1. Set option "Override thumbnail settings" to "Yes"

`https://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=ngg_display_settings`

1.1. in BASIC BASIC THUMBNAILS

1.2. in BASIC EXTENDED ALBUM

2. In template write `thumbnail_width` and `thumbnail_height`

`echo do_shortcode( '[nggallery id=1 template="your_template" thumbnail_width="229" thumbnail_height="331"]' )`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to select all the images in the gallery then chose Create New Thumbnails from the Bulk Actions dropdown. You can enter the required dimensions for your thumbnails and it will only affect that gallery

https://code.google.com/p/nextgen-gallery/issues/detail?id=63#c6